# Ethernet shield with arduino gets stuck

Tags: network-programming, arduino

I have a problem with the Ethernet shield.

This is the sketch I have wrote

```
void loop() {
  wdt_reset ();

  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    wdt_reset();
    if (client.available() > 0) {
      char thisChar = client.read();
      Serial.write(thisChar);
      RXtext += thisChar;
      // --------------------- this one repeat for few other strings ----
      if (RXtext.indexOf("L1_On") >= 0) {
        // do stuff
        RXtext = GetStat();  // get system status and replay
        server.print(RXtext);
        Serial.println(RXtext);
        RXtext = "";

        wdt_reset();
      }
      // ---------- end of repeat -------
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason the arduino gets stuck after few times I connect to it
it does not reset the wtd and it gets reset and the it looses the IP and gets `255.255.255.255` IP.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the connection at the end of your loop:

```
client.stop();
```

Otherwise you'll run out of connections and the thing will lock up and the watchdog timer will time out.

According to the [Ethernet library docs](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet): *The library supports up to four concurrent connection (incoming or outgoing or a combination)*